# How to check or ignore MacOS preferences from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, macos, cross-browser

I have 2 major problems with a custom `wheel` event on MacOS:

1. Inertial Scroll generates a flurry of `wheel` events, had to debounce the event listener.
2. MacOS swaps `deltaX` with `deltaY` when shift is pressed, this is governed by OS settings. This is the thing i do manually inside the event listener. Currently I don't know how to solve this problem.

I want either to detect these settings values from JS or to turn them off on the browser page / dom element.

Comment: JavaScript ain't going to turn off settings

Comment: Well did you look at e. shiftKey ?

Comment: @epascarello for example you can disable MacOS scrollbar behavior for an element with style `::-webkit-scrollbar { -webkit-appearance: none; }`. I want a trick like this, not an OS settings change.

Comment: Obviously i did look at `e.shiftKey`, i have `let xScrollLeftDelta = ev.shiftKey ? ev.deltaY : ev.deltaX;`, but MacOS swaps deltas before the event listeners runs.